# How do I eliminate spaces between variables and strings within an input in python?

Tags: python, input, concatenation

```
int(input("Please enter number ",num,":")
```

I want it to output as: "Please enter number (num): " #no spaces between '(num)' and ':'

When I try to use sep='', i get an error that I can't use that within and input().

Comment: Don't count on `input` for formatting, do it your self: `str(num)+":"` will leave no space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us old style % formatting, .format() or use f-strings (python 3.6+) to format your text:

```
num = 42
tmp = int(input( "Please enter number %s:" % num))
tmp = int(input( "Please enter number {}:".format(num)))
tmp = int(input( f"Please enter number {num}:"))
```

Output (trice):

```
Please enter number 42:
```

See

- [old style % vs .format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)
- [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You should use string formatting to construct the string yourself.

Either using `.format`

```
num = 5
int(input("Please enter number {}:".format(num)))
```

Or using `f-strings` for python 3.6+

```
num = 5
int(input(f"Please enter number {num}:"))

#Output:
Please enter number 5:
```